# Check EditText for character count

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I writing Android app via Xamarin (C#)

I have EditText field. And have check for NullOrEmpty.

```
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (ulitsa.Text) ) {
                Toast.MakeText (this, "Заполните поле 'Ваша Улица'", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
            }
```

I want to set max and min character filters. Min-3, Max-6 ,and if user don't have this count of characters show toast notification.

How I can realize this?

Answer (score 1):

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                //Here, get text length:
                Integer len = myEditText.getText().toString().length();

               // Then, depending on the length display the toast and do what you want
            }
        });
```

But you can actually set the max length programmatically:

```
InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(6);
myEditText.setFilters(filterArray);
```

Comment: This is Java code. I use C#. I write it on my question.

Comment: What about this: `myEditText.SetFilters (new global::Android.Text.IInputFilter[]{ global::Android.Text.InputFilterLengthFilter (6)});`

Comment: Have this   Error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'InputFilterLengthFilter' cannot be used like a method.

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(kod.Text ) || kod.ToString().Length < 3 ||kod.ToString().Length > 3 )
            {
                Toast.MakeText (this, "Заполните поле 'Код'", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tel.Text ) || tel.ToString().Length < 1 ||tel.ToString().Length > 7)
            {
                Toast.MakeText (this, "Заполните поле 'Телефон'", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
```